# Avoid repetition in tests when using Python's unittest subTest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm having trouble trying to come up with a elegant solution for this situation.

Let's say I have a unittest in Python that will test several elements from an iterable. Since this iterable is costly to build in memory, I want to build it only once trough the [`setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) method. Then, in each test, I want to sequentially pass each element in the iterable to the test, which I can to using the [context manager and the `subTest` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest). This is all fine.

The following code is an example of a mock test case doing exactly what I've described:

```
import unittest

class NumberTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.numbers = []
        for x in range(1000):
            cls.numbers.append(x)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        del cls.numbers

    def test_number_is_even(self):
        for n in self.numbers:
            with self.subTest(current_number=n):
                self.assertEqual(n % 2, 0)

    def test_number_is_odd(self):
        for n in self.numbers:
            with self.subTest(current_number=n):
                self.assertEqual(n % 2, 1)

    def test_number_is_positive(self):
        for n in self.numbers:
            with self.subTest(current_number=n):
                self.assertTrue(n > 0)

    def test_number_is_negative(self):
        for n in self.numbers:
            with self.subTest(current_number=n):
                self.assertTrue(n < 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What bugs me here is that the lines `for n in self.numbers: with self.subTest(current_number=n): . . .` are repeated for each test method. Is there any way to avoid this? I know I could simply clump all `self.assert` statements together in a single method, but this defeats the purpose of having different tests for different aspects in the first place.

In my mind the "ideal" solution would be to, somehow, `yield` the values from the iterable (maybe through the `setUp` method? No clue) and pass these values to each test method before yielding the next one. but I have no idea how to actually do this, especially since it involves a context manager... Has anyone got any other solutions, or are there simply no workarounds for this?

Comment: Welcome jfaccioni.  You say you test the elements of an iterable - unit-testing, however, is to test code to see if there are any bugs in the code.  Maybe this is a misunderstanding.  If you are trying to find bugs in code, could you please show that code?  Otherwise, we are probably not talking about unit-testing here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I want to do is to test a class I've made. In my actual code, instances of this class are built by reading input values from a long file (microscopy detection data), one instance per line. For the tests I've created a mock data file from which I instantiate mock instances of the class in the `setUpClass` method. But now that I wrote this, I realize that this may not be unit-testing at all... since I'm testing different instances of the class, not the code itself. I'm not used to unit-tests so I may have approached the problem with the wrong mindset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy solution is to outsource `for` and `with` statements to a decorator. It still needs a line per test case though:

```
from functools import wraps
from unittest import TestCase


def for_each_number():
    def decorator(test_func):
        @wraps(test_func)
        def wrapper(self: TestCase):
            for n in self.numbers:
                with self.subTest(current_number=n):
                    test_func(self, n)

        return wrapper
    return decorator


class NumberTest(TestCase):
    # ...

    @for_each_number()
    def test_number_is_even(self, n):
        self.assertEqual(n % 2, 0)

    @for_each_number()
    def test_number_is_odd(self, n):
        self.assertEqual(n % 2, 1)
    # ...
```

Of course this does *not* run just once over your iterable as your ideal solution would do. For this you would need to decorate your whole class. This seems possible with the `@parameterized_class` decorator from the [parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized) library. Never used this decorator on my own though.